# Capturing live output of a script in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this Python script for traffic analyzing:

```
import socket, sys
from struct import *
#create an INET, STREAMing socket
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
except socket.error , msg:
    print 'Socket could not be created. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

# receive a packet
while True:
    packet = s.recvfrom(65565)

    #packet string from tuple
    packet = packet[0]

    #take first 20 characters for the ip header
    ip_header = packet[0:20]

    #now unpack them :)
    iph = unpack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s' , ip_header)

    version_ihl = iph[0]
    version = version_ihl >> 4
    ihl = version_ihl & 0xF

    iph_length = ihl * 4

    ttl = iph[5]
    protocol = iph[6]
    s_addr = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[8]);
    d_addr = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[9]);

    print 'Version : ' + str(version) + ' IP Header Length : ' + str(ihl) + ' TTL : ' + str(ttl) + ' Protocol : ' + str(protocol) + ' Source Address : ' + str(s_addr) + ' Destination Address : ' + str(d_addr)

    tcp_header = packet[iph_length:iph_length+20]

    #now unpack them :)
    tcph = unpack('!HHLLBBHHH' , tcp_header)

    source_port = tcph[0]
    dest_port = tcph[1]
    sequence = tcph[2]
    acknowledgement = tcph[3]
    doff_reserved = tcph[4]
    tcph_length = doff_reserved >> 4

    print 'Source Port : ' + str(source_port) + ' Dest Port : ' + str(dest_port) + ' Sequence Number : ' + str(sequence) + ' Acknowledgement : ' + str(acknowledgement) + ' TCP header length : ' + str(tcph_length)

    h_size = iph_length + tcph_length * 4
    data_size = len(packet) - h_size

    #get data from the packet
    data = packet[h_size:]

    print 'Data : ' + data
    print
```

Now, I want to capture the output of this script for writing to a label. I tried with subprocess.Popen, but didn't work because it should be run as sudo.
How can I do this on Tkinter?

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to the socket and specify a host/port before you receive:

```
s.connect((host, port))
```